# Метод split() выводит undefined

Tags: javascript

Разбивая строку на массив методом split() через разделитель (", ") получаю alert-ы с ожидаемыми результатами, после этого получаю alert-ы с сообщением "Вам письмо undefined" количество не желательных сообщений равно количеству символов в разбиваемой строке

```
var youMessage= "Вам сообщение ";
var names = 'Roman, Artur';
var arr = names.split(", ");
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ){
alert(youMessage + arr[i]);
}
```

Пробовал экранировать запятую, результат тот-же.

Comment: А почему цикл до `names.length`, а не до `arr.length` ?

Comment: Чему, по-Вашему, равно names.length в условии окончания цикла?

Comment: Позор! я невнимательный осёл... Всё верно arr.length Всем спасибо !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var youMessage= "Вам сообщение ";
var names = 'Roman, Artur';
var arr = names.split(", ");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    alert(youMessage + arr[i]);
}
```